# How can firmware loaded into a PIC16F87XA detect if Program Memory Code Protection is enabled?

Tags: pic

The PIC's (PIC16F87XA) firmware can be programmed by an external programmer and have the *Flash Program Memory Code Protection* bit set or cleared.

How can the firmware *check* that the protection is enabled?

---

The *configuration word* (address 2007h) has a *Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit* (bit 13).

```
CP: Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit
1 = Code protection off
0 = All program memory code-protected
```

The *configuration word* appears to be inaccessible for writing by the firmware per [PIC16F87XA 14.1 Configuration Bits](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582b.pdf).

> It is important to note that address 2007h is beyond the
>   user program memory space which can be accessed
>   only during programming.

As there is no need for the firmware to write the *configuration word*, loss of write access is not important.

The *configuration word* also appears to not have read access per the same 14.1.

---

Is there any way for the firmware to read the *Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit*, a copy of it, checksum/parity the firmware including the *configuration word*, somehow assess  **or test** if the firmware is protected?

---

One can re-connect an external programmer and attempt to read the firmware and either succeed or fail as a test.  Yet that is not the firmware itself doing this assessment.

I suspect there is no published solution - I hope I am wrong.

Comment: what happens if firmware tries to read protected memory ?

Comment: @jsotola My calls to a function that implements [3.5 Reading Flash Program Memory](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582b.pdf) to read Flash Program Memory works as expected for low addresses yet does not yield expected results for x2007.   I will review its assembly to see details of how it might be failing.

Comment: i checked the data sheet. internal reads of the flash memory are not inhibited, only external reads are inhibited. so, there appears to be no way internally to determine the protection bit state.

Comment: @jsotola Thank for [that info](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342394/how-can-firmware-loaded-into-a-pic16f87xa-detect-if-program-memory-code-protecti#comment811536_342394).  I reviewed code assembly.  Tested: When code uses a 16-bit address above 0x1FFF, the data read via `EEADR, EEADRH, EECON1:EEPGD:1, EEDATA, EEDATH`, is as if the upper 7 bits are 0.  [Addresses above the range
of the respective device will wraparound to the
beginning of program memory (pdf 3.0)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582C.pdf).  So no success that route.